# the item appears unintentionally

Tags: angular, typescript

When I click on "Market", the "Item" page is hidden. (for now it's ok)

[image]

[image]

My problem is that if I click on "Currency"

[image]

The "item" is displayed, I don't understand why?
Because, the item is not in the currency page....

[image]

**admin.component.html**

```
<ul class="nav-links">
   <li [ngClass]="{ selected: selectedTab === 'market' }">
      <a
         routerLink="market"
         (click)="selectElementMenu(); selectedTab = 'market'"
         >
      <i class="bx bx-grid-alt"></i>
      <span class="links_name">Market</span>
      <i class="bx bx-chevron-down" *ngIf="selectedTab != 'market'"></i>
      <i class="bx bx-chevron-up" *ngIf="selectedTab == 'market'"></i>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li *ngIf="hidden">
      <a routerLink="item">
      <span class="links_name" style="padding-left: 75px">Item</span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li [ngClass]="{ selected: selectedTab === 'currency' }">
      <a
         routerLink="currency"
         (click)="selectElementMenu(); selectedTab = 'currency'"
         >
      <i class="bx bx-grid-alt"></i>
      <span class="links_name">Currency</span>
      <i class="bx bx-chevron-down" *ngIf="selectedTab != 'currency'"></i>
      <i class="bx bx-chevron-up" *ngIf="selectedTab == 'currency'"></i>
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**admin.component.ts**

```
showSideBar: boolean = false;

  elementMenu: boolean = false;
  selectedTab!: string;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  toggleSideBar() {
    this.showSideBar = !this.showSideBar;
  }

  selectElementMenu() {
    this.elementMenu = !this.elementMenu;
  }
```

I can give you the code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zfs44w?file=src/app/admin/admin.component.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are just toggling one variable `hidden` and not doing any other checks, so when it becomes truthy it will show. So if you want to show it only if the selected tab is market you need to add that as a condition too:

```
<li *ngIf="hidden && selectedTab === 'market'">
```

This can become real messy real fast with lots of conditions, I would instead use an array, with nested array (if subroutes exists...) to loop in template to show any main routes and subroutes.

Comment: the line `<li *ngIf="hidden && selectedTab === 'market'">` is added where, please? I am lost in my code...

Comment: in your `li`, where you already have `*ngIf="hidden"`